# VBA find same and different entries of two lists

Tags: vba, performance, excel, comparison

What I start with would be two lists with something like this:

**List 1**

```
Roger | 1.81 | ...
Amy   | 1.66 | ...
Tom   | 1.85 | ...
Peter | 1.32 | ...
Karen | 1.20 | ...
Lukas | 1.76 | ...
```

**List 2**

```
Josef | 2.02 | ...
Lukas | 1.76 | ...
Amy   | 1.66 | ...
Carl  | 1.72 | ...
Roger | 1.81 | ...
```

Where `|` indicates a new column in the same row.

---

What I want in the end:

**Same**

```
Roger | 1.81 | ...
Amy   | 1.66 | ...
Lukas | 1.76 | ...
```

**In 1 but not 2**

```
Karen | 1.20 | ...
Peter | 1.32 | ...
Tom   | 1.85 | ...
```

**In 2 but not 1**

```
Carl  | 1.72 | ...
Josef | 2.02 | ...
```

Where the order of the entries doesn't matter.

---

I can't believe this isn't natively implemented in Excel. I need this all the time at work, and have to stupidly loop through each and every entry of the two list in VBA, which takes some time for thousand of entries (t ∝ n*m). Surely there must be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

Using data in A1:A6 and B1:B6, where A is list A and B is list B, using an array formula will give you the "native" way of doing it in Excel.

This will give you the row numbers of A for the (is in A and B) criteria, you can mess with this for the others. Use in C1 and Drag the formula down to get results.

`=SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6)>0,ROW($A$1:$A$6)),ROWS($C$1:$C1))`

Comment: Thank you for you answer!

I translated the code to german (with ";" instead of ","), I changed my language settings, and used the original code. Both was without avail.
Is it without a typo?

What would be the equivalent VBA-Code?
I want to express by the way, that the lists are of more than one column.

Comment: Did you enter it as an array formula CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER?

Comment: I entered it as it stands there.
I did now copy it in a cell and pressed CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, but I don't understand what this should do.

At any rate, could you give the VBA-equivalent, since this is how I am going to use it; and - no offence for the excel lovers out there - better to implement (=If it works for you, it works for me).